# How to convert a 2D array to a structured array using view (numpy)?

Tags: python, view, numpy, structured-data

I am having some problems assigning fields to an array using the view method. Apparently, there doesn't seem to be a control of how you want to assign the field.

```
a=array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]) # 3x2 matrix
#array([[1, 2],
#       [1, 2],
#       [1, 2]])  

aa=a.transpose() # 2x3 matrix
#array([[1, 1, 1],
#       [2, 2, 2]])

a.view(dtype='i8,i8') # This works
a.view(dtype='i8,i8,i8') # This returns error ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
aa.view(dtype='i8,i8') # This works
aa.view(dtype='i8,i8,i8') # This returns error ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

In fact, if I create aa from scratch instead of using transpose of a,

```
b=array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
b.view(dtype='i8 i8') # This returns ValueError again.
b.view(dtype='i8,i8,i8') # This works
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can set the fields to represent rows or columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a standard array in NumPy, some contiguous blocks of memory are occupied by the data. The size of each block depends on the `dtype`, the number and organization of these blocks by the shape of your array. Structured arrays follow the same pattern, except that each block is now composed of several sub-blocks, each sub-block occupying some space as defined by the corresponding `dtype` of the field.

In your example, you define a `(3,2)` array of ints (`a`). That's 2 `int` blocks for the first row, followed by 2 other blocks for the second and then 2 last blocks for the first. If you want to transform it into a structured array, you can either keep the original layout (each block becomes a unique field (`a.view(dtype=[('f0', int)]`), or transform your 2-block rows into rows of 1 larger block consisting of 2 sub-blocks, each sub-block having a `int` size.
That's what happen when you do `a.view(dtype=[('f0',int),('f1',int)])`.

You can't make larger blocks (*ie*, `dtype="i8,i8,i8"`), as the corresponding information would be spread across different rows.

Now, you can display your array in a different way, for example display it column by column: that's what happen when you do a `.transpose` of your array. It's only display, though, ('views' in the NumPy lingo), that doesn't change the original memory layout. So, your `aa` example, the original layout is still "3 rows of 2 integers", that you can represent as "3 rows of one block of 2 integers".

In your second example, `b=array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])`, you have a different layout: 2 rows of 3 `int` blocks. You can group the 3 int blocks into one larger block (`dtype="i8,i8,i8"`) because you're not going over a row. You can't group it two by two, because you would have an extra block on each row.

You can transform a `(N,M)` standard array into only (1) a `N` structured array of `M` fields or (2) a `NxM` structured array of 1 field and that's it. The `(N,M)` is the shape given to the array at its creation. You can display your array as a `(M,N)` array by a transposition, but that doesn't modify the original memory layout.

Comment: This probably came late since I found a temporary work around, but thank you for your help!

Comment: I see, transpose only changes the display, but not the initial data structure. Definitely not intuitive, but at least now i know what to avoid. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

when you specify the view as `b.view(dtype='i8, i8')` you are asking `numpy` to reinterpret the values as set of tuples with two values in them but this simply isn't feasible since we have 3 values which isn't a multiple of two, its like reshaping the matrix where it would generate a new matrix of different size, numpy doesn't like such things.

Comment: This sounds good, but how come that `b.view(dtype="int8,int8")` works very well for me?

Comment: well thats cause `int8` and `i8` are two different types, `int8` means 8 8 bit ints, `i8` means a 1 64 bit int, the default type ... basically `i1` == `int8` and `i8` == `int64`